# How to refactor a large Ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller class that is large enough to be a bad practice (Rubocop throws this warning: Class definition is too long).

The class has many private methods, all of them calculate paths to redirect to, so it's a controller matter.

How could it be refactored?

Example code:

```
class PostController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    # ...
  end

  # more resources methods

  private

  def post_params
    # ...
  end

  def post_url(post)
    if params['submit-save'] || params['submit-publish']
      url_for [:edit, post]
    else
      url_for [:review, post]
    end
  end

  def next_post_url(post)
    next_post = post.find_next

    if next_post
      url_for [:edit, post]
    else
      some_path(next_post)
    end
  end

  # some more methods
end
```

Comment: Maybe you can groups paths together by relevance and then delegate the tasks to smaller controllers.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example, please?

Comment: How about moving all those private methods into the model, or a service object, including the route helpers with "include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers"?

Comment: Please post some code examples.

Comment: If the class is too large, it's probably encompassing to many concepts into one class. See some refactoring techniques [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring#List_of_refactoring_techniques). Try splitting out different concepts into new classes (see the extract class section on the wikipedia page). For example a `car` class could be broken into different classes for the engine, and the tires, etc. It's hard to know where to refactor without seeing the code itself.

Comment: @Adam just imagine a controller with the typical methods (new, create, etc), and a lot of private methods that return different routes depending on the parameter they get. All routes are related to the controller.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that Rubucop is wrong and that your class is the size it should be?

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, but I'm kind of perfectionist :)

Comment: I tend to trust my own opinion over what some dumb tool says. The tool doesn't understand the code, what it is for, or why it is structured the way it is. Sometimes refactoring just to satisfy some artificial standard makes a big confusing mess.

Comment: @David, I can imagine all I like, but it's hard to say whether your code is good or bad without seeing it. Your best bet is the have someone do a code review on the class and tell you if it's too big, or if that is the only way it really works.

Comment: You could nip and tuck and nick and cut... But first of all, you should post some code for the people to stop speculating...

Comment: If you don't use these private methods for before_actions or before_filters, you should probably move them into a helper module. As they appear, I doubt they could be written differently.

Comment: @RubyRacer could them be a view concern then? because helpers are intended for the view layer, aren't they?

Comment: I don't know layers, sorry... I've been using helper methods from helper modules for my controllers since Day-1 in rails. Helpers I believe can be used in any context, as long as they remain consistent to the requirements. So, you have helpers in views (like form helper) and helpers for controllers (rails generate scaffold produces them)... I guess, beyond my knowledge, helpers will be used in other layers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, extracting conclusions from the comments, I liked these 2 ideas:

- Common sense. Only you as the developer know how the code should be structured, so tools can only suggest, but you have the final word. Rubocop can be configured through comments in the code to disable some checks.
- In case of refactor, private methods in a controller could be extracted into a helper.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion on your question, my thought would be to identify if the various private methods that are calculating paths for redirection could belong in a special purpose class that abstracts the various aspects of the path calculation logic or possibly just a module that the controller mixes in. The right answer will depend greatly on exactly what your logic looks like in the various private methods. A simple module is not likely the right approach since you're just moving the code somewhere else to meet an arbitrary metric. Identifying the reason for all the private methods and coming up with a better abstraction is probably the right approach, but there are different patterns that may come into play.

Many of the same patterns discussed in this article will apply to overweight controllers as well as models: [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the last word is going to be always from the developer, but if you add a tool like rubocop is to encourage you to write a better code so It makes no sense to me adding rubocop and then disabling some checking.
I would'n use helpers methods either, the reason behind is that a class should have only one responsibility, so it should have only one behaviour. People tend to put methods of all types inside helpers, methods with completely different behaviours which give to that class many different responsibilities. I would just use a helper, if all of its methods have just one and only one purpose.
In your particular case I would be more tempted to extract knowledge into plain classes. Try to identify different behaviours and encapsulate them into classes.
In that case it looks like you have some kind of url builder so a posible solution could be something like :

```
class PostController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(url_builder.post_url)
    # ...
  end

  # more resources methods

  private

  def url_builder
    UrlBuilder.new(self, params)
  end
end

class UrlBuilder
  def initialize(self, params)
    @self = self
    @params = params
  end

  def post_url(post)
    if params['submit-save'] || params['submit-publish']
      self.url_for [:edit, post]
    else
      self.url_for [:review, post]
    end
  end

  def next_post_url(post)
    next_post = post.find_next

    if next_post
      self.url_for [:edit, post]
    else
      some_path(next_post)
    end
  end
  private
  attr_reader :self, :params
end
```

This is not a fully working example as I don't know the entire implementation of your controller, is just a posible solution which will need some adjustments. A couple of things to say about that solution are:

- I would move the class into a completely different file.
- I don't like the idea of passing self between objects, I don't thinks is a good
  idea to pass the context of an object into another object, it creates
  coupling between the two of them because one need to know about the
  other one context, but in this particular case is the only way I can
  see, if you want to use the url_for helper methods available in the
  controller otherwise you will have to make your own url builder. If
  anyone have others ideas please share it with us.
- If you discover that there are more than just one behaviour then I
  would split then into more than one class, as many as behaviours you find.